# calculate sum of list properties excluding min and max value with linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, linq-to-objects

This is what I have so far:

```
decimal? total = list.Sum(item => item.Score);
```

What I would like to do is to exclude the min and max value in the list and then get the total value.

Is it possible to do all that in one linq statement?

Comment: You can try something like list.OrderBy(item => item.Score).Skip(1).Take(list.Count - 2).Sum(item => item.Score);

For reference, I hate myself now, and this is probably the most unoptimized piece of garbage.

Comment: You can definitely do it with an accumulator with *one* evaluation of the enumerable. (I mean using Aggregate).

Comment: Why do you want a single statement? Wouldn't a simple `list.Sum(item => item.Score) - list.Max() - list.Min()` be more readable? I doubt iterating the list three times will be the bottleneck of your application.

Comment: ... See my answer below for an answer which only enumerates the whole Enumerable once with O(1) memory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
list.OrderBy(item => item.Score)
    .Skip(1)
    .Reverse()
    .Skip(1)
    .Sum(item => item.Score);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try ordering the list first, then skip first item (minimum) and take all but the last (maximum) from the rest:

```
decimal? total = list.OrderBy(x => x.Score)
                     .Skip(1)
                     .Take(list.Count - 2)
                     .Sum(x => x.Score);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the nicest code imaginable, but it does have the benefits of

- only enumerating through the entire collection **once** (though it does get the first value three times).
- Not require any much more memory than that to hold the IEnumerator and two `Tuple<int, int, long, long>` objects (which you'd not have if using `OrderBy`, `ToList` and sorting, etc.). This lets it work with arbitrarily large IEnumerable collections.
- A single Linq expression (which is what you wanted).
- Handles the edge cases (`values.Count() < 2`) properly:

  - when there's no values, using `Min()` and `Max()` on an IEnumerable will throw an `InvalidOperationException`
  - when there's one value, naïve implementations will do something like `Sum() - Min() - Max()` on the IEnumerable which returns the single value, negated.

I know you've already accepted an answer, but here it is: I'm using a single call to [Enumerable.Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548744).

```
public static long SumExcludingMinAndMax(IEnumerable<int> values)
{
    // first parameter: seed (Tuple<running minimum, running maximum, count, running total>)
    // second parameter: func to generate accumulate
    // third parameter: func to select final result
    var result = values.Aggregate(
            Tuple.Create<int, int, long, long>(int.MaxValue, int.MinValue, 0, 0),
            (accumulate, value) => Tuple.Create<int, int, long, long>(Math.Min(accumulate.Item1, value), Math.Max(accumulate.Item2, value), accumulate.Item3 + 1, accumulate.Item4 + value),
            accumulate => accumulate.Item3 < 2 ? 0 : accumulate.Item4 - accumulate.Item1 - accumulate.Item2);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You can swap out the invocations to `First` with `int.MaxValue` and `int.MinValue` as priming values to avoid accessing the `IEnumerable` more than once here. Also, if the OP is concerned about performance it's cheaper here to use a mutable struct as an accumulator, and if he's  *really* concerned about performance, it's cheaper to do all of this in a simple `foreach` loop. I agree with the spirit of this though, the accepted answer, while somewhat elegant and fine for small collections being called infrequently, is horrendous in terms of space and time complexity.

Comment: You're absolutely right about the struct. I couldn't think of any existing `struct` in the BCL which fitted the bill. Even worse, you'll get an `InvalidOperationException` if using my method with no values. Worse still, I originally called it `AverageExcludingMinAndMax` when it returned the sum. I've updated my answer accordingly to handle the zero-value case and seed with `int.MinValue` and `int.MaxValue`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude *all* min- and max-values, pre-calculate both values and then use `Ènumerable.Where` to exclude them:

```
decimal? min = list.Min(item => item.Score);
decimal? max = list.Max(item => item.Score);
decimal? total = list
    .Where(item=> item.Score != min && item.Score != max)
    .Sum(item =>  item.Score);
```

Comment: This begs the questions of whether or not he wants to exclude all instances or a single instance of the min/max score.

Comment: what if I have two or  three scores which are min or max value, will that exclude all three or only one? I need only one to be removed. Thanks for your help @Tim

Comment: @Laziale: the above approach exclude all min- and max-values. This is as i have understood your requirement.

Comment: This O(n) is nice, agreed with @AlexeiLevenkov. However, why not just make the third line `decimal? total = list.Sum(o => o.Score) - (min + max);`? Then it does exactly what OP wants.

Answer (score -2):

You should pre-process list before sum to exclude min and max.